# SQL Syntax Error-MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am new to SQL and learning the basics. I just typed in those code and I keep getting a missing operator error.

```
INSERT INTO Student(StudentID,FN,LN,DOB,Email,PermanentAddress,ContactInfo,TheHousing,TheSponsor,TheSchool,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate)
Values (‘ST9032’,’Yuri’,’Kwon’,’05/09/1990’,’yk@gmail.com’,’32 SNSD St’,’7183294123’,’HO9032’,’SP9032’,’SC9032’,’06/04/2005’,’06/30/2009’)
```

I have checked the syntax and it appears right to me but clearly something is wrong. Can someone please clarify my error? Thank You

Comment: Apostrophes  not `’` but  `'`

Comment: The date constants are not correct, MS Access uses double quotes for strings, and the single quotes are curly.

Comment: Oh I see. Lesson learned. Thank you Lad and Gordon.